# Blocking read with closed file descriptor

Tags: c, unix, pipe, ipc

I have three processes organized in a circular link: P1->P2->P3->P1. I have 3 unnamed pipes for each of the three links. Each process reads an integer from his neighbour on the left and writes an integer to the neighbour on the write. After some time an termination condition will be satisfied at one of the processes. This will make that process close his open file descriptors and terminate. However, the other processes still are able to write to the now closed fd and the reads are blocking. Have I misunderstood how unnamed pipes are really working?

```
void monitor(int *fdr, int *fdw, int pid) {
  int A,B,ret,avg;
  char send_buf[10], recv_buf[10];
  srand((unsigned int) fdr);

  A = 20;
  close(fdr[1]); close(fdw[0]);

  while(1) {
    B = rand() % 30;
    avg = (A+B)/2;
    if (avg > 20) {
      printf("P%d computes to high avg. Quit!\n",pid);
      break;
    }

    sprintf(send_buf, "%d", avg);
    printf("P%d will write %s\n",pid,send_buf);
    ret = write(fdw[1],send_buf,strlen(send_buf)+1);
    if (ret == 0) {
      printf("P%d cant write. Quit\n",pid);
      break;
    }
    printf("P%d successful write=%d\n", pid, ret);
    ret = read(fdr[0], recv_buf,10);
    if (ret == 0) {
      printf("P%d cant read. Quit\n",pid);
      break;
    }

    printf("P%d reads %s\n",pid,recv_buf);
    A = atoi(recv_buf);
  }
  // Closing filedescriptors should also break the other
  // processes out of the while loop
  close(fdr[0]); 
  close(fdw[1]);
  printf("P%d closed all descriptors\n",pid);
}
```

Comment: Are you handling signals somewhere else if your code? IIRC, closing the pipes to another process like this should cause the process to receive a SIGPIPE. If you forked the processes, are you sure you closed the pipe instances in the parent process?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do close the pipe instances in the parent process. But the problem seems to arise from creating a pipe in a parent process that two child processes should use. I decided to solve it using named pipes (FIFOs) and had non problems.